# Resizable navbar in jQuery

Tags: jquery, media-queries, navbar, resizable

I want to do some navbar but I'm beginner in jQuery.

For resolution 768px and more I've made menu, which opens after cursor hover on it (via media queries in CSS).

On the other hand for less than 768px resolution I made menu which opens after click (via jQuery).

Here is a code:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {

    $('ul').hide();

    $('.navb').click(function() {
      $('.main').slideToggle();
      $('.main>li>ul').slideUp();
      $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideUp();
    });

    $('.sub-1').click(function() {
      $('.main>li>ul').slideToggle();
      $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideUp();
    });

    $('.sub-2').click(function() {
      $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideToggle();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background: darkkhaki;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul li {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }
  .main > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
  }
}
.navb {
  background: darkkhaki;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navb span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navb visible-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="sub-1">Link 3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="sub-2">Link 3.4<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right hidden-xs"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.4</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.5</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I open website on less than 768px width everything works great but after resize to 768px+ it doesn't. Same thing happens when I first open it on 768px+ width and resize it to lower resolution.

I know there is a resize() function in jQuery, but I read that it's not recommended. I'm sure there is an easy solution for my problem, but I didn't find it. How can I fix it? Please help me. I also would be greteful if someone can give me link to script with navbar which I want.

Comment: If it works fine, what's your issue? In situations like this, put yourself in a real world situation. Does the menu work fine on mobile? Does it work fine on Desktop? Nobody is going to resize your page when browsing JUST to see if the menu breaks - nobody changes their browser size when browsing a web page!

Answer (score 0):

You have done a slight mistake in your js code. You have defined all your event handlers inside `if` condition now what happens is when first time your js runs and your windows width is greater than `768px` then no handler will going to apply on you elements because your `if` statement get fail. Now when you resize your window less than `768px` then nothing will happen because you haven't used `resize()` event which you don't want to use.

You can do something like place your windows width checking inside your `click()` event handler. Now there is one more issue your `ul` hiding. You can't just hide your `ul` in js without `resize()` event.

But css got you cover you can do something like

```
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .main > li:first-child {
         border-top: 1px solid gray;
      }
     ul{
         display:none;
     }
   }
```

Now when your window resizes less than 768px it will hide your `ul` tag too.

you also have to add some css in `min-width` media query too

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }
  .main > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
  }
//this new style is added here and used important so to get importance than jquery's own css
  ul.main{
    display:block !important;
  }
}
```

```js
$(function() {

    //$('ul').hide();

    $('.navb').click(function() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.main').slideToggle();
        $('.main>li>ul').slideUp();
        $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideUp();
      }
    });

    $('.sub-1').click(function() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.main>li>ul').slideToggle();
        $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideUp();
      }
    });

    $('.sub-2').click(function() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.main>li>ul>li>ul').slideToggle();
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background: darkkhaki;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul li {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }
  .main > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
  }
  ul.main{
    display:block !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
  }
  ul{
    display:none;
  }
}
.navb {
  background: darkkhaki;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navb span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navb visible-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="sub-1">Link 3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="sub-2">Link 3.4<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right hidden-xs"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.4</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3.4.5</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p1ddnn99/